# how to get data after end drag on my color picker?

Tags: flutter, dart

Now, Is everytime I drag my picker color is changed. I didn't want to fire event everytime. After end, I want to get color code..

```
return GestureDetector(
  onPanDown: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
  onPanStart: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
  onPanUpdate: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
  child: Stack(children: [frame, content, thumb]),
);


  /// calculate colors picked from palette and update our states.
  void handleTouch(Offset globalPosition, BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    Offset localPosition = box.globalToLocal(globalPosition);
    double percent;
    if (widget.horizontal) {
      percent = (localPosition.dx - widget.thumbRadius) / barWidth;
    } else {
      percent = (localPosition.dy - widget.thumbRadius) / barHeight;
    }
    percent = min(max(0.0, percent), 1.0);
    setState(() {
      this.percent = percent;
    });
    switch (widget.pickMode) {
      case PickMode.Color:
        Color color = HSVColor.fromAHSV(1.0, percent * 360, 1.0, 1.0).toColor();
        widget.colorListener(color.value);
        break;
      case PickMode.Grey:
        final int channel = (0xff * percent).toInt();
        widget.colorListener(Color
          .fromARGB(0xff, channel, channel, channel)
          .value);
        break;
    }
  }
```

tried panEnd not working

onPanEnd: (end) => handleTouch(end.velocity.pixelsPerSecond,context),

full code https://github.com/Cricin/ColorPicker-flutter/blob/master/lib/color_picker.dart

Answer (score 2):

`onPanEnd`'s details don't record any details of positions.
In fact, there's no property within the `GestureDetector` class that would help you record the final positon.

**Proposed Solution:**

The final position will be in the last call of `onPanUpdate` details.

Instead of calling a heavy function like `handleTouch` to compute every time, you can just update the positions to a variable ( `finalPostion` ).

When `onPanEnd` is active, use the variable( `finalPostion` ) that can be accessed within the GestureDetector widget.

```
onPanUpdate: (details) => updateFinalPosition(details.globalPosition),
onPanEnd: handleTouch( finalPosition, context)
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me to implement a feature I needed in my app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**What went wrong**

```dart
onPanDown: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
onPanStart: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
onPanUpdate: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
```

Try to remove some of the following drag callbacks that doesn't suit your desired behavior.

**Deep dive to the callbacks**

`onPanStart`

```dart
/// A pointer has contacted the screen with a primary button and has begun to
/// move.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [kPrimaryButton], the button this callback responds to.
final GestureDragStartCallback onPanStart;
```

`onPanUpdate`

```dart
/// A pointer that is in contact with the screen with a primary button and
/// moving has moved again.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [kPrimaryButton], the button this callback responds to.
final GestureDragUpdateCallback onPanUpdate;
```

**Now you can just use onPanDown**

```dart
return GestureDetector(
  // Might worth noting, review the behavior of your choice onPanDown onPanEnd
  onPanDown: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
  // Depends if you still need this.
  // onPanStart: (details) => handleTouch(details.globalPosition, context),
  child: Stack(children: [frame, content, thumb]),
);
```

Comment: onPanEnd is not available `details.globalPosition`

Comment: Hi @BloodLoss, in that case. Can't you just use the `onPanDown` without the `onPanUpdate`?